# Is there a way to download Symfony 2 with PHP config files instead of YAML?

Tags: php, symfony, yaml

I have searched high and low but I don't see a clear way to do this. I simply want all the YAML files in the config folder to be replaced with PHP files. Where can I find this? Or is there documentation on it?

Comment: sorry for asking, but is there any specific reason you want this? yaml just rocks as config format. why would someone want to use the verbose php syntax for configuration? if you are worried about perfomance, it all gets transformed and cached to php before execution...

Comment: Not at all, perfectly valid question (and argument). The reason is, I actually like the verbose syntax. It helps me to know _exactly_ what's going on in my configuration. Plus, I'm currently unfamiliar with YAML and I'd like to hit the ground running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe anyone has made a distribution like this. The Standard Edition uses a mix of YAML, annotations, and XML (mostly YAML). YAML is incredibly easy and intuitive, though. I don't think you'll have a problem using it for the standard configs. You can still use PHP for any bundles you create on your own. Also, most bundles use YAML as their default, so it would probably be faster to just use those rather than convert their examples to PHP.

Comment: Yeah, you're probably right. Except, let's say I want my configs to be handled by the application via the database. How could I make a database call in YAML? Obviously, I could just write the YAML configs to the config.yml file upon a change. But sometimes it's just easier to throw a db call in there when performance isn't really a concern. What do you think?